# DSC not pulling config

Tags: powershell, dsc, powershell-v5.0

my DSC node is not pulling the DSC config from my SMB DSC server. Get-DSCConfigurationStatus says the pull was successfull but Get-DSCConfiguration remains the same(old config).

Im testing it with a HelloWorld config where a file is created on the C drive.
When i delete the file Get-DSCConfiguration says "Enusre: absent" but when it pulls the new config, it should be "ensure: present". I have no errors or anything else. Idk why it isn't pulling correctly.

My  DSC LCM config:

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString “PASSWORD” -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential (“SERVUSER”, $secpasswd)

[DSCLocalConfigurationManager()]
configuration PullClientConfig
{
    param(
    [PSCredential]$DomainCredential
)

    Node 'localhost'
    {
        Settings
        {
            RefreshMode = 'Pull'
            RefreshFrequencyMins = 30
            RebootNodeIfNeeded = $false
            ConfigurationID = '2fda9b6d-e1be-46a9-8b92-e25cb17026cd'

        }

         ConfigurationRepositoryShare SmbConfigShare
        {
            SourcePath = '\\SERVER\SHARE'
            Credential = $mycreds
        }

        ResourceRepositoryShare SmbResourceShare
        {
            SourcePath = '\\SERVER\SHARE'
            Credential = $mycreds

        }
    }
}
$cd = @{
    AllNodes = @(
        @{
            NodeName = 'localhost'
            PSDscAllowPlainTextPassword = $true
        }
    )
}
```

My HelloWord config:

```
Configuration HelloWorld {

    param (
        [string[]]$ComputerName = "localhost" # i have changed this parameter to the servername
    )

    # Import the module that contains the File resource.
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName PsDesiredStateConfiguration

    # The Node statement specifies which targets to compile MOF files for, when this configuration is executed.
    Node $ComputerName {

        # The File resource can ensure the state of files, or copy them from a source to a destination with persistent updates.
        File HelloWorld {
            DestinationPath = "C:\HelloWorld.txt"
            Ensure = "Present"
            Contents   = "Hello World from DSC!"
        }
    }
}
```

Update-DScConfiguration says that there is no newer config, so it wont pull. Do i understand DSC Right it has a config and the node trys to suit this config. So it basicaly has to pull a config again and apply it, instead it keeps the old config, refuses to pull. But the old config is wrong.... i dont get it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was The ConfigurationMode, which had to be set under Settings in DSCLocalConfigurationManager to ApplyAndAutocorrect!